# canon set a variable using the if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, set

I have a problem with setting the @temp variable.
The if statement below fails.  I have tried various combinations with quotes, using the SELECT command, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!
Mike

```
SET @Stime := '6:30PM';

IF ( CHAR_LENGTH(@Stime) = 6, SET @temp := 'one', SET @temp := 'two');
```

Comment: what programming language is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's mySQL

The IF() function returns a value if a condition is TRUE, or another value if a condition is FALSE.
In your case this code will update temp with one or two depends on the length.

```
SET @Stime := '6:30PM';

SET @temp = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@Stime) = 6,'one','two');
```

Comment: It is MySQL.  Thank you for your help.  Still trying to get used to the syntax.

Comment: Please consider accepting this or any other answer, so the question will not remain open.